# Limiting refreshes in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, refresh, powerquery

PROBLEM: I've a table which is refreshing when I don't need it to, and it's taking forever.  In Power Query - I have several queries ganged together.

*NewAddsStage* reads in a directory with ~10 workbooks from a networked sharedrive, appends the data together, filters it down a lot, and loads to a table.  It takes about 4 minutes to refresh.

*NewAddsRoll* uses *NewAddsStage* as a source, performs a several Table.Join's and rolls up the data, creating a couple columns which hold objects of type list.  It forms a connection only.

*Report1*, *Report2*, etc use *NewAddsRoll* as their source, do different kinds of filtering, and load to tables (which are in the same workbook as the *NewAddsStage* table.)

Every time I go to edit the *Reports*, *NewAddsStage* refreshes, re-reading all its workbooks, and that takes way too long.  I want them to just use whatever data is held in *NewAddsRoll*, without refreshing it or *NewAddsStage*.  I've fooled around with *Data > Connections > Properties* for the connections, but it doesn't seem to help.

Do I need to put the *NewAddsStage* table into a separate workbook in order to stop it from refreshing?  The underlying data changes, but less than monthly.  I want to only have things refresh when I invoke the refresh manually.  Is there a way?

FWIW, I'm running PQ on the desktop, in Excel 2013, under Windows 7, with the Formula.Firewall off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, having your *NewAddsStage* table in another workbook isn't a bad idea if it's a very large set of data and you are only refreshing that data once a month. That aside, I feel like there is probably a "proper" way to do what you want, but I have found a bootleg way that seems to "work" even though it looks redundant.

Since you are already loading *NewAddsStage* into a table in your workbook, create a (connection only) Query from that table. Then have all your other queries run off of that as a base instead of *NewAddsStage*. This will give you access to the data in *NewAddsStage* without it being linked to all the workbooks and trying to refresh all the time.

Comment: Thanks, Wedge!  So nice to come back from the holiday break and find a good answer!